# Webpack: "Unable to start the dev server. Error: The dev server is not running on port 3000." unless compiled twice

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, webpack, office-js, yeoman-generator

To play with an SSO project in office.js, I am using :

- https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office 1.9.2,
- node v16.16.0,
- npm v8.11.0,
- Visual Studio Code Version: 1.71.2,
- Windows NTx64 100.19044.
- This also uses webpack (webpack@5.74.0).

I got this to work (required some changes to the generated project).

Now I am adapting the project to my needs and got it to build.

But it now fails to start the webserver.

On the terminal in VScode, I issue :

"npm start", which is composed of these other scripts:

"start": "npm run build:dev && concurrently "npm run start:server" "npm run sideload"",

"build:dev": "webpack --mode development",

"sideload": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",

"start:server": "office-addin-sso start manifest.xml",

The terminal tells me:

"Starting the dev server... (webpack serve --mode development)
Unable to start the dev server. Error: The dev server is not running on port 3000."

What I have tried:

- I have looked through the webpack window output, tells me: "webpack    5.74.0 compiled successfully in … ms" (but more below).
- I looked through %LocalAppData%\npm-cache_logs.
- I scoured the    %LocalAppData%\Temp\OfficeAddins.log.txt
- I killed and restarted everything I could think of.
- I checked the port is not used (w/ netstat -ano | findstr :3000)
- I changed the port, gives same error on that port (package.json : "config": {"dev-server-port": 3001})
- I checked the code for remaining errors (w/ office-addin-lint check)
- I checked the office certificates are installed (w/  npx office-addin-dev-certs verify)
- I issued: npm update

Then with the terminal window and webpack still showing, it occured to me to open another terminal on the side and start another npm start.

This time, I got a somewhat shorter output of webpack in another node window (showing only one line webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in … ms", the webpack window above from the first terminal showed this line twice).

Below is a diff of the webpack window output (run from terminal2 on the left; the port 8080 was changed automatically to the free one; so some webserver went up after all? though I could not browse to e/.g. https://localhost:3000/fallbackauthdialog.html).

At this point, I can sideload the office add-in in Excel without add-in error, press its taskpane's button and get debug output (on terminal 2, not in the debug console).

Can you please help get back to a more standard debug configuration, and point out to me what I may be doing wrong, or what other diagnostics I could run?

[image: winmerge webpack output terminal2/terminal1]